# Changing column type from varchar to datestamp in Redshift

Tags: sql, casting, amazon-redshift

I am trying to create a view from a table and change one of the column types from varchar to a datestamp.

My `original_talbe` looks like this:

```
A       B                       C         D
80.00   2020-03-07 19:36:50     testing   approved
80.00   2020-03-07 19:46:50     testing   approved
```

All of my columns are varchar, I would like to create a view `new_view` which column type for `B` would be datestamp.

I have tried:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW schema.new_view
AS SELECT * from schema.original_table
alter view original_table alter column date_from_original_table type timestamp using date_created::timestamp;
```

But I am getting an error:

> Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "view"

How can I achieve the outcome of a view having datestamp format for column `B`?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the value when you construct the view:

```
create view schema.new_view as
    select a, b::timestamp, c, d
    from schema.original_table;
```